# Can you add friends on the PSN website?

Tags: psn

I looked in the ["friends" section of the PSN website](http://us.playstation.com/myfriends/), and I couldn't find any way to search for other friends to add.

Can this be done anywhere online or can it be only done through the console system?

Comment: For those interested, this is possible now (I can't officially answer the question, so posting as a comment). Just click the Friends icon (2 faces) on my.playstation.com, then search for a "gamertag" and add.

Comment: Just commenting to pile on to SilverSideDown, wish you could officially answer... It's possible through the website

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The ability to add friends via the website is a popular feature request (a quick Google search will turn up dozens of threads going back years asking for it), but it has never been added.

So as of now, you can only do it through the PlayStation 3, PlayStation Vita, or PlayStation 4 (oddly, you can't even add friends on the PSP).

Comment: The PSP has basically no PSN support except as a download portal, so it's not surprising. It was made before the PSN after all

Answer (score 10):

Still can't add friends from the website, but you can use the official PlayStation **iOS/Android app**:

[image: Make More Friends]

Answer (score 8):

Very old question, but in case someone is googling this, now you can do it:

https://my.playstation.com/ and navigate to "Friends". From there you can now search, add friends, manage requests and everything else you could only do in the app before.

Comment: Is this still true? That URL just redirects for me in my mobile browser, at least, and I don't see a "Friends" link.

Comment: No good – as of today this link just redirects to playstation.com.